# How to find minimum date from different xml date nodes using xslt

Tags: xslt

I created the html file using xml and xslt.
I need minimum date using xslt. here my task is i have one xml file with different nodes like flightList,HotelList,CarList,.... I need to get the lowest date from all nodes(flightList,HotelList,CarList).
I have created application as mentioned below.

### My XML File written like this:

### My xml document written like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <!--<xsl:template match="TRSummary">-->


    <!--Flight TravelDate Minimum date-->

    <xsl:variable name="Flight">
        <xsl:for-each select="TRSummary/FlightList">
            <xsl:sort select="number(substring(TravelDate, 7, 4))" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="number(substring(TravelDate, 3, 2))" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="number(substring(TravelDate, 1, 2))" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="TravelDate"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!--Hotel CheckInDate Minimum date-->

    <xsl:variable name="Hotel">
        <xsl:for-each select="TRSummary/HotelsList">
            <xsl:sort select="number(substring(CheckInDate, 7, 4))" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="number(substring(CheckInDate, 3, 2))" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="number(substring(CheckInDate, 1, 2))" order="ascending"/>

            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="CheckInDate"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!--Car CarFromDate Minimum date-->

    <xsl:variable name="Car">
        <xsl:for-each select="TRSummary/CarList">
            <xsl:sort select="number(substring(CarFromDate, 7, 4))" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="number(substring(CarFromDate, 3, 2))" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="number(substring(CarFromDate, 1, 2))" order="ascending"/>

            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="CarFromDate"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="arrays"  >
        <Item>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Car"/>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Hotel"/>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <xsl:value-of select="$Flight"/>
        </Item>
    </xsl:variable>
<xsl:param name="array" select="msxsl:node-set($arrays)"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="TRSummary">
        <xsl:value-of select="$array/Item"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
<TRSummary>
```

### The above code am getting output :

24/04/2012 22/04/2015 29/04/2011

### I need output like this:

29/04/2011

How to get minimum date.
plz guide me ASAP.

Thanks&Regards,
Ramu.

```
    <FlightList>
        <TravelDate>28/04/2014</TravelDate>
    </FlightList>
    <FlightList>
        <TravelDate>24/04/2012</TravelDate>
    </FlightList>
    <FlightList>
        <TravelDate>30/04/2013</TravelDate>
    </FlightList>
    <HotelsList>
        <CheckInDate>29/04/2015</CheckInDate>
    </HotelsList>
    <HotelsList>
        <CheckInDate>22/04/2015</CheckInDate>
    </HotelsList>
    <HotelsList>
        <CheckInDate>31/05/2016</CheckInDate>
    </HotelsList>
    <CarList>
        <CarFromDate>29/04/2015</CarFromDate>
    </CarList>
    <CarList>
        <CarFromDate>29/04/2011</CarFromDate>
    </CarList>
    <CarList>
        <CarFromDate>23/04/2015</CarFromDate>
    </CarList>
</TRSummary>
```

Comment: The output you show us is **not** the output received when running your code.

Comment: Have you got your expected output and actual output the wrong way around? Is it the case that you are currently getting the output `29/04/2011`, but you need the output to be `24/04/2012 22/04/2015 29/04/2011`? If so, could you edit your question accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: I  got same output, please use same xml and xslt what i have shared you. i am getting same out put.  i need minimum date.

Comment: I  got same output, please use same xml and xslt what i have shared you. i am getting same out put.  i need minimum date. please guid me, how to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your current output is just `29/04/2011`, and your expected output is `24/04/2012 22/04/2015 29/04/2011` then the problem is because of this code

```
<xsl:for-each select="TRSummary">
    <xsl:value-of select="$array/Item"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Firstly, you don't really need the `xsl:for-each` on `TRSummary` here because there is only one such element in the XML. However, the real issue is the `xsl:value-of` is only going to output the value of the first `Item` in your `array` variable.

You really need to do the `xsl:for-each` on the items, like so

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$array/Item">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

On the other hand, if you only want the minimum of the three dates, you can just do another sort on the items, like so

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$array/Item">
        <xsl:sort select="number(substring(., 7, 4))" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:sort select="number(substring(., 4, 2))" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:sort select="number(substring(., 1, 2))" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

If this is the case, you could just simplify your whole stylesheet to this, and do away with the need for the node-set

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="TRSummary/*">
            <xsl:sort select="number(substring(*, 7, 4))" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="number(substring(*, 4, 2))" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:sort select="number(substring(*, 1, 2))" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```